# What S= ' ‘ +S + ' ' means? Why space needs to concatenate to both end?

Tags: python, string

> Given a string s, return the number of substrings that have only one distinct letter.
>
> Input: s = "aaaba"
> Output: 8
> Explanation: The substrings with one distinct letter are "aaa", "aa", "a", "b".
> "aaa" occurs 1 time.
> "aa" occurs 2 times.
> "a" occurs 4 times.
> "b" occurs 1 time.
> So the answer is 1 + 2 + 4 + 1 = 8.

I am looking through this piece of code from one of the leetcode problem, have trouble understanding
`S = ' '+ S + ' '` this part. Can anyone help me to understand? Thanks

```
def countLetters(self, S: str) -> int:
    S = ' '+ S + ' '
    total, count = 0, 1
    for i in range(1, len(S)-1):
        if S[i] != S[i-1]:
            count = 1
        else:
            count += 1 
        total += count
    return total
```

Comment: It appears to provide artificial boundaries around the string, so that `S[i] != S[i-1]` checks every character of the original string without producing any `IndexError`s.

Comment: @chepner if we change S[i] !=s[i+1] do we still need artificial boundaries around the string?

Comment: Assuming the algorithm is otherwise correct, removing the spaces means you have to do something special with `S[0]` and `S[-1]`, as they don't have a previous or subsequent character (respectively) to compare to. Adding the spaces removes these special cases. (As it appears that `S` is assumed to not contain spaces originally, so that `S[0] != S[1]` is guaranteed to be true.) I don't know that the trailing space is necessary; it seems to be ignored completely given the `range` being iterated.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the great explanation. Not sure how to mark as a good answer

Comment: I'll try to add my comment as an answer that makes sense without having to actually understand what the code is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the spaces, the handling of the original `S[0]` would have to be treated as as special case. By adding a space to the beginning of the string, `S[1]` (the original first character) is handled like all the others: it is compared to `S[0]` (which, by definition, appears guaranteed to be different from `S[1]`).

It's not clear to me that the trailing space is necessary, as the index `i` never reaches it.